# Google Analytics for Android v3 campaign Tracking Not Working

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using Campaign Measurement - Android SDK V3. I've followed all the steps described at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns 
Used the code and made changes in manifest.xml as mentioned in above link. I've tried this in emulator.  This is the error log am getting.can anyone help me?

```
W/ActivityManager(61): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START    cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }: not found
W/GAV3(1008): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
I/GAV3(1008): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
```

Does the missing AnalyticsService error message have any significance?

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file here ?